# How to install an application on Elastix?

Tags: asterisk, sip, pbx, freepbx, elastix

**Does anyone know, how to install an application on Elastix?** In my case it is Answering Machine Detection(AMD). I need this application to detect outgoing calls, and if the answering machine is fax, hangup.
I tried to modify config files(modules.conf, extensions.conf, extensions_override_elastix.conf, amd.conf) as it is told in Asterisk documentation and forums, but non of it worked. CLI console doesn't show AMD output, and I think that AMD isn't even enabled there. 
I've been looking for the answer for 3 or 4 weeks now and found almost nothing.
There must be something I've overlooked.
Maybe I should change something in the database(asterisk) or Elastix PBX settings?

Here's what I did:

- Modified */etc/asterisk/amd.conf* file. Appended this to the end:
  [general]
  initial_silence = 2250
  greeting = 1500
  after_greeting_silence = 1250
  total_analysis_time = 5000
  min_word_length = 100
  between_words_silence = 50
  maximum_number_of_words = 8
  silence_threshold = 256
- Modified */etc/asterisk/modules.conf*. Appended this to the end:
  load = > app_amd.so
- Modified /etc/asterisk/extensions_override_elastix.conf
  [outgoing]  ;context
  exten => s,1,Answer()
  exten => s,n,AMD()
  exten => s,n,NoOp(${AMDSTATUS})
  exten => s,n,GotoIf($[${AMDSTATUS}=HUMAN]?humn:mach)
  exten => s,n(mach),WaitForSilence(3000,1,20)
  exten => s,n,Playback(${VOICEFILE})
  exten => s,n,Hangup()
  exten => s,n(humn),WaitForSilence(500)
  exten => s,n,Playback(${VOICEFILE})
  exten => s,n,Hangup()
- Seeking for settings in database, in case if Elastix works through its database. Elastix writes logs into asterisk.cdr table - that's the only useful thing I've found.

I suppose, the CLI console should "say" something related to AMD application when I am calling, but it works as usual, without AMD enabled.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What you see if you put in asterisk cli `module show like amd`?

Comment: `Module                     Description                                                   Use Count 
app_amd.so             Answering Machine Detection Application   0         
1 modules loaded.`
So, there is module called app_amd.so, but it's not used.

Comment: I think calls just do not hit your context.

Answer (score 1):

You should add at options page to dialling param "M(amd)"

After that you should create macro-amd like described in manual.

That macro will be fired on call after call answered and before call bridged to other peer.